# dc.js clear all charts

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I have a html page with 5 dc.js charts.

I would like to clear all the charts (completely remove them from the page) given a certain event.

something like:

```
dc.clearAll();
```

I checked the API's and such a method does not exist.

I implemented a workaround with jquery:

```
$('#chart1').empty();
$('#chart2').empty();
$('#chart3').empty();
$('#chart4').empty();
$('#chart5').empty();
```

The workaround works but i was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do it, preferably with the API.

Comment: You could also do it with d3 if you don't want the extra dependency of jquery - `d3.selectAll("svg").remove()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If when you create the charts you name them, you can use the api like so:

```
chartOne.resetSvg()
chartTwo.resetSvg()
```

etc. This will leave behind an empty `<svg>` tag in the div.

Answer (score 2):

`d3.selectAll("svg").remove()` worked for me.